# Using uneven offsets for centering content in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3, I'm trying to center a image on its own row. Here is what I have, which responds well across display sizes:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 text-center">
     <img src="img.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>                                        
</div>
```

However, `.img-responsive` sets `max-width`: 100%. The image is too large on some displays. For example, I'd rather have `col-lg-1` than `col-lg-2`.

Obviously, I could do `col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-5` but the content will be off-center.

Is there an equivalent to `col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-5.5`, or some other method to center content in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say no by default. But It can be possible with [Bootstrap customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) then you can define your custom responsive grid column with `@grid-columns`. You can specify 16.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-7 text-center">
     <img src="img.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>                                        
</div>
```

Or you can just style your image to be smaller width.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 text-center">
     <img src="img.jpg" class="img-resize img-responsive">
  </div>                                        
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .img-resize {
       width: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. In `.img-resize`, would I use `max-width` rather than `width`? On very small screens, I don't want the image to be that large.

Comment: Can, but you are also able to specify the image size for different screen by using @media rule. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Unfortunately, that's exactly what I was hoping to avoid. Doesn't seem practical to do this for many images.

Comment: Since it is depends on your screen size so practically you should define specific image size with popular @media rule